# what is the meaning `HTMLDivElement.<anonymous>`?

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, dom, error-handling

when i traversing dom.. I got  a error message  `null at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous>` in browser console log ..
what is  the meaning  `HTMLDivElement.<anonymous>`  ?

***Browser*** Google Chrome

**Image**

[image]

Comment: We could probably give you a more specific answer if you provided a [mcve] and told us what browser you're using, so we can see this for ourselves. :-)

Comment: when i click on `margin` space i got this error .. if i replace with `padding` it's okay...   give some time to put example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just means that the method on `HTMLDivElement` that the error originated in or passed through is either anonymous (it doesn't have a name) or has the name `<anonymous>` (possible though unlikely). Most functions have names, but not all do, and they aren't required to in JavaScript.

Comment: would you  can give more specific answer ? or it's enough ? ...

Comment: @noor - The question update just tells us what browser. It doesn't have enough additional information to help you more. Again, please see: [mcve]

Comment: i put the pic...i told about when i traversing dom i got this error ... i think i do not need to add code.. if you need i will add example code..

Comment: @noor - Please read [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65166529/what-is-the-meaning-htmldivelement-anonymous/65166551?noredirect=1#comment115207796_65166529) again. Note the "so we can see this for ourselves" part.

Comment: That said, what more do you need? You asked what it means, and the above answers that. There's some method (probably an inner/private method) that's running into an unexpected `null` and throwing.